# Бесплатный аналог ERWin

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, erwin

Есть ли бесплатный аналог ERWin для проектирования БД?

В инете находил довольно древнюю софтину...

А есть что-нибудь, что развивается?

Comment: Здравствуйте. А какого функционала вам будет достаточно? Например, нужна ли генерация кода? есть вот [такой](http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/) онлайн проект

Answer (score 5):

**Toad Data Modeler**
https://www.quest.com/products/toad-data-modeler/

**SQL Power Architect**
http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect

**Open System Architect**
http://www.codebydesign.com/SystemArchitect/downloads/

**DB Designer**
http://www.fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/

**Mogwai ERDesigner NG**
http://mogwai.sourceforge.net/erdesignerng.html

Comment: Toad Data Modeler достаточно вкусно выглядит. Но не ужели его бесплатная версия не имеет ограничений по функциональности по сравнению с платной? Я единственное ограничение нашел в кол-во пользователей...